# increase length of custom field text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the Wordpress plugin Woocommerce. The system uses attributes to display product information such as weight, height, and so on. I guess the attributes feature is based on Wordpress custom fields. One of the attributes I have is a description. The problem I'm facing is that WP is automatically truncating the content I enter here and limiting it to about 200 characters.

After poring over the code and various searches on google I landed with nothing. So I was wondering if someone might know how I can increase the length of these custom fields/attributes to accept something like 400 characters.

Thanks in advance,
Sukrit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer after spending some time searching through the code and the database. With some great advice from Woocommerce team members I finally settled with the following solution.

I went into the database and changed the name column of the {wp}_terms table from VARCHAR (200) to VARCHAR(1000).

Seems to have sorted the problem, at least until the next upgrade.